# Add Style to Child of a td-Element

Tags: jquery, css

In my table, the td-Elements contain sometimes a textarea, sometimes an input. 
With a click on a td, I add the class 'active' to the element.

```
// Add Class to active cell
$(function() {
    var table = $('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
      $('.table tr td').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Now, I want to change the textalign of the inputs or the textareas.

```
$("#left_align_btn").click(function() {
     $('td.active').css('text-align', 'left');
});
```

How can I achieve that the style will added to all the "Childs (sometimes an input, sometimes a textarea..." of the active td?

Thank you

Comment: `$('td.active').find('input, textarea').css('text-align', 'left');`?

Comment: FWIW: `$('.table tr td').removeClass('active');` You probably want `$('.table tr td.active').removeClass('active');`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that makes some sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) or [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) in your selector:

```
// Child:
$('td.active > input, td.active > textarea').css('text-align', 'left');

// Descendant:
$('td.active input, td.active textarea').css('text-align', 'left');
```

Comment: Great! Thank you T.J Crowder

Answer (score 0):

To get all the children of td, use

```
 $('td.active *').css('text-align', 'left');
```

To get only the input elements, you can use like,

```
$('td.active :input').css('text-align', 'left');
```

Comment: this make everything textalign left not particulary for the input and textarea.

Comment: @Benjamin see the second part

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `float` instead of `text-align` as follow :

```
$("#left_align_btn").click(function() {
     $('td.active').css('float', 'left'); \\use float instead of text-align
});
```

or if you want to align text of td's tag than you have to go as follow :

```
$("#left_align_btn").click(function() {
     $('td.active').find("input, textarea").css('text-align', 'left');
});
```